# Building a VS2010 project consumes extra resources

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build-process

I have many projects I work on normally, but I have one that consumes a max of CPU resources after building, system (windows server 2008) becomes very slow . and this issue has started last week, I don't remember that I have changed neither project nor VS2010 settings.

What can be the problem  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Visual studio is probably configured to max out the threads during the build process, you will see lots of temporary threads being created, you can limit this in

'Tools>Options>Project and Solutions>Build and Run'

and modify the 'maximum number of parallel project builds'

Comment: thanks for reply, I have set it to two but it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Are you compiling C++? What does task manager show? Does it show lots of cl.exe or VCBuildHelper.exe's being spawned? You could attach processmonitor to Visual studio and monitor what it is doing, creating lots of threads, reading reg keys etc.. So your other projects do not show this behaviour?? Do you have any includes that reference network shares? It is possible that this could be adding a delay to the compilation as it tries to access the resources, Process monitor will show what files it is trying to read.

Comment: I am compliling WPF C# Project.The task manager doesn't show any of the  cl.exe or VCBuildHelper.exe processes. Sorry, how can I attach vs2010 to process monitor to examin ?

Comment: Download processmonitor from here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 then run it, at first it will capture all events, 'File->Capture Events' to stop it, then you need to add a specific filter for visual studio, 'Filter->Filter..', select 'Process Name'>'is'>'DevEnv.exe' click' Add', 'Apply', now clear the display 'Edit->Clear Display', now start capturing 'File->Capture Events' and look for create Thread actions, Open File etc.. and see if anything is suspicious

Comment: Thanks for the useful tool though, I've found a huge amount of System Activity (it reads my project files many times) and Registry Activity but not a lot of Thread Activity (actually I cannot juge if its suspicious or not)

Comment: Sounds strange, check what resources its trying to read many times and see if the structure of your project is correct. Do your other projects compile fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8683/discussion-between-edchum-and-hichem-sharaeen)